# Efficiently derive two versions of a common function based on a boolean flag

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have a function `foo` that comes in two flavors that is passed via a flag.

```
void foo(isModeA) {

    // a lot of shared code

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
       for(int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
           if(isModeA){
              // do modeA code
           } else {
              // do modeB code
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this method is time critical and I want to avoid the conditional in the innermost loop. I have two rather unsatisfying solutions so far:

- create two versions of `foo` by duplicating the code: `fooModeA()`, `fooModeB()` and move the if logic to the function call
- use templating to create two versions of the function. Again move the
  if logic to the function call

I wonder if there is a cleaner solution here. Is there a way to keep the original code but convince the compiler to create two functions for me implicitly? Or maybe a clever way to restructure the code?

Comment: you can try multithreading

Comment: @Saramali I doubt this will help.

Comment: Depends on what you've written this code for. The solution does not need to be problem specific but it's good if you can tell your goal.

Comment: Why do you use `isModeA` as a function?

Comment: @A.K. thanks - that was a typo - fixed it.

Comment: @MilindW, the output of the function is a vector of integers that are created by a form of graph traversal. The difference between the modes is the mathematical function that creates the integers from the nodes.

Comment: Before trying to rearrange your code or rewrite it using some advanced concepts suggested below, make sure that the conditional indeed poses a performance problem. Depending on the CPU you use, it can be well predicted and cost little.

Answer (score 4):

Given the code:

```
const int N = 50;
const int M = 60;

void doModeA(int i, int j);
void doModeB(int i, int j);

void foo(bool isModeA) {
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
       for(int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
           if(isModeA){
              doModeA(i, j);
           } else {
              doModeB(i, j);
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Clang / LLVM will compile this into something like:

```
define void @_Z3foob(i1 zeroext) local_unnamed_addr #0 {
  br i1 %0, label %3, label %2

; <label>:2:                                      ; preds = %1
  br label %9

; <label>:3:                                      ; preds = %1
  br label %4

; <label>:4:                                      ; preds = %3, %4
  %5 = phi i32 [ %6, %4 ], [ 0, %3 ]
  tail call void @_Z7doModeAii(i32 %5, i32 0)
  tail call void @_Z7doModeAii(i32 %5, i32 1)
  ....
  tail call void @_Z7doModeAii(i32 %5, i32 58)
  tail call void @_Z7doModeAii(i32 %5, i32 59)
  %6 = add nuw nsw i32 %5, 1
  %7 = icmp eq i32 %6, 50
  br i1 %7, label %8, label %4

; <label>:8:                                      ; preds = %9, %4
  ret void

; <label>:9:                                      ; preds = %2, %9
  %10 = phi i32 [ %11, %9 ], [ 0, %2 ]
  tail call void @_Z7doModeBii(i32 %10, i32 0)
  tail call void @_Z7doModeBii(i32 %10, i32 1)
  ...
  tail call void @_Z7doModeBii(i32 %10, i32 58)
  tail call void @_Z7doModeBii(i32 %10, i32 59)
  %11 = add nuw nsw i32 %10, 1
  %12 = icmp eq i32 %11, 50
  br i1 %12, label %8, label %9
}
```

Which implements the optimization you're asking for. So just write the code that's readable, and let the compiler do its job. That's what it's there for.

Comment: relying on the compiler's optimization is not the best way to optimize the code

Comment: If you can get isModeA declared as a const outside the loop then the optimisation can be relied on.
It doesn't feel like "good programming", but duplication is definitely "bad programming".

Answer (score 3):

In your example you can avoid the inner loop conditional duplicating just a couple of lines of code (the nested `for` loops):

```
void foo(isModeA) {

    // a lot of shared code

    if (isModeA()) {
       for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
           for(int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
              // do modeA code
           }
       }
    } else {
       for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
           for(int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
              // do modeB code
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create two different `foo` functions, you can still use lambdas and invoke them in place with the *right code* to execute. This way the `if` is evaluated only once and everything is packed within `foo`.
As a minimal, working example:

```
template<typename F>
void foo(F isModeA) {
    // a lot of shared code

    [](auto f){
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                f();
            }
        }
    }(isModeA()
        ? []() { /* code for modeA */ }
        : []() { /* code for modeB */ }
    );
}

int main() {
    foo([](){ return true; });
    foo([](){ return false; });
}
```

Adjust the capture lists according to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

This is [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14), but something that most compilers implemented very early in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) support.

```
void foo(bool isModeA) {

  // a lot of shared code

  auto loops = [&](auto isModeA) {
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
        if(isModeA){
          // do modeA code
        } else {
          // do modeB code
        }
      }
    }
  };
  if (isModeA) {
    loops( std::integral_constant<bool, true>{} );
  } else {
    loops( std::integral_constant<bool, false>{} );
  }
}
```

This should compile down to exactly the code you want on any real C++ compiler with optimization enabled.

If you return from within the `loops` things are a bit harder.  A `std::optional` can help here (where you return an optional return type, and outside you:

```
  auto loops = [&](auto isModeA)->std::optional<R> {
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
        if(isModeA){
          // do modeA code
        } else {
          // do modeB code
        }
      }
    }
  };
  if (isModeA) {
    if (auto r = loops( std::integral_constant<bool, true>{} ))
      return *r;
  } else {
    if (auto r = loops( std::integral_constant<bool, false>{} ))
      return *r;
  }
}
```

or `boost::optional`.  For `void` return, just return a `bool` from `loops`.

Answer (score 0):

How do you use `isModeA`? Is it getting modifies into the loop?
If that's not the case you can use the function pointer here if you want to preserve the code structure which will eliminate the `if(isModeA)` statement somewhat like

```
void fooModeA(){}
void fooModeB(){}

void foo(isModeA) {

// a lot of shared code

  void (*foo)() = NULL;
  if(isModeA){
    foo = fooModeA;
  }
  else{
    foo = fooModeB;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
     for(int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
        foo();       
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: But this solution would cost me a function call in the innermost loop. Wouldn't that be less performant than just keeping the if?

Comment: @cel You're looking for performance in the wrong place. The problem with function calls is not that they cost much but they are called many times. If the function is powerful and has many subtasks that it has to do before returning a bool, that's where the performance is degraded as it would be called more often. See Mike's answer https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/318055/how-much-do-function-calls-impact-performance

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to push the problem "uphill" to the caller, in C++17 you could declare declare isModeA as a template specifier, and use if consexpr (isModeA), so your code still looks the same.

The caller would then have to choose to call `Foo<true>()` or `Foo<false>()`,
or you could write another `Foo(F isModeA)` that contains that branching decision.

But I still think this is premature optimisation, at least in this simplified world of the example.